# Calling .NET Cryptography from VBA

Tags: vba, cryptography, sha1

I am trying to generate an SHA-1 hash in VBA (which I am not very familiar with). In .NET it is pretty straightforward, using `System.Security.Cryptography`. One method is as follows:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
...

byte[] data;
// fill data here
SHA1Managed sha = new SHA1Managed();
bytes[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(data);
```

How would you go about calling this from VBA? I got as far as this

```
Dim oSHA As Object
Set oSHA = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed")
```

but I can't figure out how to pass a `Byte` array to `ComputeHash`

```
hash = oSHA.ComputeHash(oBytes)
```

This throws an error about the parameter being incorrect. How do you convert it to a format accepted by .NET?

Note that I do NOT want to use VBA calculations for SHA-1 (too slow, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel). It would also be nice if I didn't have to write any wrappers for the .NET portion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ComputeHash` is overloaded, you need to specify which one you want to call, in this case:

```
hash = oSHA.ComputeHash_2(bytes)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much! How do you know which overload is which? Trial and error? Also, is this going to stay the same always (documented somewhere)?

Comment: The convention is `Name_X` where `X` is `2` to `N` based on the order of declaration of the overloaded method (There is no `Name_1`, `Name` itself is used for the first). I used ILSPY to search for `ComputeHash` in `SHA1Managed` and saw the second implementation was the one that took `byte[]`.

Answer (score 4):

From `System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm`:

- `ComputeHash_1(inputStream As stream)`
- `ComputeHash_2(buffer As byte())`
- `ComputeHash_3(buffer As byte(), offset As int, count As int)`